# Xamarin forms slider disable tap/click

Tags: xamarin, slider

I want to make a iphone like slide to unlock slider within xamarin forms.
So I want to disable the slider to be clicked on 100%.
I tried to add a tap gesture recognizer but unfortunatly this doesn't work/

Anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Forms can't work with anything more complicated than tap. You have to implement a custom renderer. There is an example which does what you want:
https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleCustomGestureFrame